# How to do setTime intervel for mail sending -js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing leave system for staff.If staff request leave to the HR ,
when HR is not approval their leave request ,from that time every one hours  mail send to the HR for remainder for approval or reject that leave request.

Here is my problem i tried to send mail every one minute interval .its working.but it is continually sending mail.that's mean not working  my condition.

My conditions are ..

- if pending my leave request till  (leave status=1 ),then send every
  one hours .
- if approved my request (leave status=3 )then stop send
  mail.

Here is my code

//mail sending function ............

```
function(err, res) {
  setInterval(function(){
    if((ctx.result.leave_status === 1)&&!(ctx.result.leave_status === 3) )
    {
       console.log('resp: ' + emailsArray.toString());
       type = res.type.description;
       name = res.name.f_name;
       LeaveDetails.app.models.Email.send({
       to: emailsArray.toString(),
       from: 'gnanaseelan@gmail.com',
       subject: 'Leave Request ',
     // text: 'my text',
      html: '<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Report leave request</h1><h3>' + name + ' have requested leave</h3><ul><li><b>type: </b>' + type + '</li><li><b>duration: </b>' + duration + '</li><li><b>Number of days: </b>' + days + '</li></ul>,
      },
 function(err, mail) {
   console.log('email sent!');
     if(err !== null) {
        log.error({
        type: 'error',
        model: 'leave-details',
        method: 'create (email send)',user_id: ctx.result.user_id,
        err: err,leaveData: ctx.result,}, 'leave request-email-failed');
         } 
    else {
      log.info({
        type: 'success',
        model: 'leave-details',
        method: 'create (email send)',
        user_id: ctx.result.user_id,
        leaveDuration: ctx.result.leave_start_time + " " + ctx.result.leave_end_time,
        err: err
      }, 'leave request-email-success');
    }
        next(err);
      });
    }//if end
   },60000);
  }
```

Comment: never use `setInterval` for data pushing, unless you _also_ have all the code in place to cancel that interval when hit an error. That said, can you please look at your post, notice that the code's kind of all over the place, and edit it to look readably indented, aligned, etc? (especially note that even if your file uses tabs or four spaces, just use two spaces on SO. You have limited space to make your code show before scrollbars start popping up. Once you see a scrollbar, you probably included too much code that can't possibly all be part of an [mcve])

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Please check it out my code

Comment: please _format_ your code. Hit edit, copy it into a text editor, fix up the indentation, remove the bits that don't contribute to your problem, and then update your post with that new code. Right now, more than half the lines you've included are not related to what you're asking about. Don't include data extraction that then goes in an `html` variable that you can just set to `"<p>html goes here</p>"`, etc. Please form an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clearInterval to stop sending emails , the best tip is to set interval as a global object in constructor and then clear it when some status set , for example you have a status named "finished:false" if finished is set to "true" , clearInterval in componentWillUpdate o shouldComponentUpdate  , 
if you dont do this , your interval never finish , and it will happen until you Unmount